# Trouble following algebra in this solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm having difficulty following the algebra here between 1b.5 and 1b.6. Can anyone help me with what intermediate steps are needed?

[image: Solution]

Comment: First step: multiply both sides by $e^{kH}$ to get $a_1 e^{2kH}-(a_1-d)\cdot 1=0$.

Comment: Ah, that'll do it! Stupid dyslexic brain didn't see the negative sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the hint, I've come to this solution.

[image: solution]